# Hardhat node localhost not working. Empty host?

Tags: ethereum, hardhat

When I start a hardhat node, it starts but the address is http://::1:8545/ instead of http://127.0.0.1:8545/

```
tomi@localhost eth-dapp % npx hardhat node
Started HTTP and WebSocket JSON-RPC server at http://::1:8545/
```

Comment: The problem is with node version 17 and you can resolve this issue by using 
--hostname 127.0.0.1 parameter. 
Another way is to downgrade to node version 16.

Comment: Your method worked for me man. You should probably post it as an answer. I followed this https://medium.com/@georgeenathomas/3-step-process-to-downgrade-node-version-using-homebrew-bc0b0a72ae27 to downgrade node